# how to write the current month Dynamically in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have Column which has the label "JUL-CurrentMonth Fiscal Year To-Date"

How can i write the expression in which Current month should be populated Dynamically in the label?

I was trying this

```
"July-" &month(today) " Fiscal Year To-Date"
```

but it is not working

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get **todays date** you need to use `Now()` function.

To get Month use `Month` function.

```
"July-" & month(NOW()) & " Fiscal Year To-Date"
```

To get name of the month use `MonthName` function.

```
"July-" & MonthName(NOW()) & " Fiscal Year To-Date"
```

Comment: But the above gives me numerical month but not month name

Comment: Use `MonthName` function.